# Can I install pyenv on drive D?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I want to install pyenv in D:\Programs after git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git idk how to correct add paths and system variable. Can you please explain me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/README.md#windows) states that `pyenv` does not work in Windows, except in WSL.  You might look at `pyenv-win`.

Comment: My bad , I copied the wrong link, the question remains the same

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The page you linked to is the one I'm talking about.  If you go read that page, it states it does not work on Windows except in WSL.

Comment: He must mean this, pyenv-win: https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win. Why he hasn't corrected it is beyond me. And the question is indeed valid: very annoyingly, we're given no obvious option other than to add more clutter to drive C: